# Apple Maps requests are returning Error Forbidden 403

Tags: macos, ios7, ios-simulator, xcode5, apple-maps

I started working in an app which needs to display maps at some point. I wanted to go with apple's built in support for this(aka `Mapkit`), but haven't succeeded so far.
I started playing with mapkit using this [example](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21365/introduction-to-mapkit-in-ios-6-tutorial). The MKMapView is always displaying a blank grid, which is not the expected result.

Then I checked in the simulator *Debug >> Open System Log...* and I found the following in the responses for the map tiles requests:

```
Jan 27 21:04:33 ppp-177var5.pppi.enet.cu geod[1234] <Warning>: Error downloading resource: Error Domain=GEOErrorDomain Code=-601 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (GEOErrorDomain error -601.)" UserInfo=0x2d5ea10 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://gspa21.ls.apple.com/stylesheet/default-522.styleproto?sid=00&tk=9697a89581dee74b03f5fa7dac0dbf37&mapkey=1390864469_017ead13c5015c535f5af0b037507566, HTTP Status Code=403}
```

Also, I checked for the simulator connectivity by navigating with Safari, and DID work!.
Obviously, apple servers are returning forbidden for the maps http requests.

Here is a snapshot of debugging with Charles's (web debugger):
[image]

For more info, I am running `OS X 10.9.1(Mavericks)` on a `mac mini`. Also, I think this is not a problem of country restriction because I connected through a VPN located in the UK  and didn't work. 
I tested the Maps app provided by OS X and I got the same forbidden error.

My questions are:

1. Why is this happening?
2. What are the parameters `sid`,`tk` and `mapkey` in the query string of the map tiles requests.

Please, avoid suggesting switching to `Mapbox framework` since this is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Unfortunately nope, I had to switch to [Google Sdk](https://www.google.com.cu/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fmaps%2Fdocumentation%2Fios%3Fhl%3Des&ei=jgqCU4uTOIyUqAaD6IGAAw&usg=AFQjCNHzqO_MRuV1E6SXgCxHG8IlxdWV1g&bvm=bv.67720277,d.b2k)